# Hindi Fonts in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, hindi

In Internal preview of Hindi fonts Displays Correctly. But in Pdf It Varies .

For Example : पिता . In Pdf it Shows प िता

How to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Special characters like Hindi language symbols will be supported by few font types like Arial Unicode MS:

To Resolve this issue, Open Ireport designer and apply below properties to the report:

1. Font Name =  "Arial Unicode MS".
2. PDF font name = This property is deprecated, so leave it blank.
3. PDF Encoding = 'Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)'.

Hope this help you resolve the issue.

Regards,
Srikanth Kattam