# Exported pdf in iReport not displaying correct font

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to display a simple kannada text in *iReport*. The font I am using is Tunga.ttf and it gets embedded as subset in exported pdf but the words are not displayed correctly.

The PDF encoding option as provided by *iReport* that I am using here is Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing) ....

The following is the one I get in *iReport* preview.

[image: Internal preview]

The following is the image that is obtained when exported as PDF

[image: image that is obtained when exported as PDF]

Kindly help me out with this problem.

Comment: And which one is correct? Did you try to use [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: First one is the correct that is the internal preview. I have installed corresponding fonts in the IReport IDE using tools -> options -> fonts -> install fonts

Comment: Did you see this post: [Hindi Fonts in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23978392/876298)?

Comment: yes..i already checked that